# How to Set the Correct Permissions to Launch Neo4J on AWS EC2 via Its Bash Script?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, neo4j, permissions

I'm trying to launch Neo4J graph database on AWS using their AIM image (enteprise 3.3.9)

However, the server fails to launch the instance automatically how it's supposed to.

When I try to relaunch it using

```
systemctl restart neo4j
```

It also fails.

When I do

```
systemctl cat neo4j
```

I find the `/etc/neo4j/pre-neo4j.sh` file, which is apparently launched on the instance's startup, which, in turn launches Neo4J (when it's supposed to work):

```
[Unit]
Description=Neo4j Graph Database
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/etc/neo4j/pre-neo4j.sh
Restart=on-failure
User=neo4j
Group=neo4j
Environment="NEO4J_CONF=/etc/neo4j" "NEO4J_HOME=/var/lib/neo4j"
LimitNOFILE=60000
TimeoutSec=120
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So then I launch it manually via the bash script using the `sudo` prefix and then it starts up fine.

```
sudo /etc/neo4j/pre-neo4j.sh
```

The documentation on deploying Neo4J on an AWS server doesn't mention anything about permissions if you use their image. So what can be the problem?

I don't want to have manually launch the DB using the `sudo` — is it possible to resolve this problem by modifying the bash script itself?

..

The file `/etc/neo4j/pre-neo4j.sh` sets some environmental parameters and then launches neo4j via:

```
/usr/share/neo4j/bin/neo4j console
```

Comment: Do you have any logs when run `journalctl -u neo4j`?

Comment: Thank you, @Marcin — this helped to identify a problem with the Bashscript. You might want to post it as an answer, so I accept it.

Comment: Glad to hear. Answer added :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The solution was to use

```
journalctl -u neo4j
```

to **inspect the logs** associated with the failed start of `neo4j`. This enabled to identify the root cause, and subsequently, to fix the issue.